# Have there ever been maximum age limits for public office in the United States?

Tags: united-states, 19th-century, political-history, law

In doing some research, I came across [this obituary](http://www.findagrave.com/cgi-bin/fg.cgi?page=gr&GRid=54007043&ref=acom) in "The Sabbath Recorder"

> At his residence in Hopkinton, R. I., Sept. 18th, Deacon Daniel
>   Babcock, in his 85th year of his age, and the 59th year of his office
>   in the church, where he was a leader of the choir for about 50 years.
>   **He was early elected to different offices in the State Government,
>   which he held and honored until his age disqualified him for holding
>   office.** He was forward in every benevolent enterprise undertaken by
>   the church, and possesed a warm and tender heart towards lost sinners.
>   In his death the poor have lost a peculiar friend, his children an
>   indulgent and kind counsellor and father, his widow an affectionate
>   husband, and the church a pillar in the spiritual temple.

I find this to be ambiguous wording. Are they referring to a legal disqualification or to de facto disqualification due to infirmity, senility, etc.? Are there any instances of *de jure* age limits anywhere in the United States? Any precedent from British law?

Comment: My guess is the disqualification was self-imposed, rather than by law -- when he could no longer handle the rigors of office he stopped seeking it.

Comment: Judicial offices (viewed as public offices in some states) often have mandatory retirement ages: e.g. http://ballotpedia.org/Mandatory_Retirement, http://talkingpointsmemo.com/news/age-law-louisiana-will-oust-court-officials.

Comment: When top posts are held indefinitely, it is common to have a max age limit not only to avoid senile leaders, but to have some possibility of promotion for lesser officials.  Judicial courts are a common example, not only on US. But for elected officials a max limit do not make sense, as electors can see him talking, debating, walking and moving around during the election cycle, and they would not vote for a senile man, right? Or would he hide in a basement for the whole election cycle?  hum...

Answer (score 5):

As of 1912, Article 77 of Part 2 of the [New Hampshire constitution](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Constitution_of_the_State_of_New_Hampshi/pchGAQAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22after%20he%20has%20%20attained%20the%20age%20of%20seventy%20years%22%20%22new%20hampshire%22&pg=PA27&printsec=frontcover) said:

> No person shall hold the office of judge of any court , or judge of probate , or sheriff of any county , after he has attained the age of seventy years.

This is [still current](https://www.nh.gov/glance/judicial.htm), but article 78 now.

Also, there was a US Senate [rule](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Journal_of_the_Senate_of_the_United_Stat/WGhBcmKa8KsC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22chairman%20of%20a%20standing%20committee%20of%20the%20Senate%20after%20he%20has%20attained%20the%20age%20of%20seventy%20years%22&pg=PA35&printsec=frontcover) added in 1963:

> No Member of the Senate may serve as chairman of a standing committee of the Senate after he has attained the age of seventy years

Deacon Daniel Babcock was a judge in Washington County, Rhode Island (see [Westerly Rhode Island and Its Witnesses](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Westerly_Rhode_Island_and_Its_Witnesses/oNAaMBIFWtcC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22Daniel%20Babcock%22%20was%20a%20judge%20in%20Washington%20County&pg=PA177&printsec=frontcover), page 177).  Many states place age limits on judges, but I haven't come across any evidence so far that Rhode Island did.